# Using jQuery to Dynamically Insert Into List Alphabetically

Tags: jquery, list, dynamic

I have two ordered lists next to each other.

When I take a node out of one list I want to insert it alphabetically into the other list. The catch is that I want to take just the one element out and place it back in the other list without refreshing the entire list.

The strange thing is that when I insert into the list on the right, it works fine, but when I insert back into the list on the left, the order never comes out right.

I have also tried reading everything into an array and sorting it there just in case the children() method isn't returning things in the order they are displayed, but I still get the same results.

Here is my jQuery:

```
function moveNode(node, to_list, order_by){

    rightful_index = 1;
    $(to_list)
        .children()
        .each(function(){
            var ordering_field = (order_by == "A") ? "ingredient_display" : "local_counter";

            var compA = $(node).attr(ordering_field).toUpperCase();
            var compB = $(this).attr(ordering_field).toUpperCase();
            var C = ((compA > compB) ? 1 : 0);
            if( C == 1 ){
                rightful_index++;
            }
        });

    if(rightful_index > $(to_list).children().length){
        $(node).fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $(to_list).append($(node));
            $(node).fadeIn("fast");
        }); 
    }else{
        $(node).fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $(to_list + " li:nth-child(" + rightful_index + ")").before($(node));
            $(node).fadeIn("fast");
        });
    }

}
```

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<ol>
<li ingredient_display="Enriched Pasta" ingredient_id="101635" local_counter="1">
     <span class="rank">1</span>
     <span class="rounded-corners">
          <span class="plus_sign">&nbsp;&nbsp;+&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <div class="ingredient">Enriched Pasta</div> 
          <span class="minus_sign">&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     </span>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through your code and make sure your each(...) callback function is behaving correctly? Firebug or IE8 developer tools work great for this. You can put a breakpoint in the body of your callback.

Comment: i checked w3c. i can't find any mention of the `ingredient_display`, `ingredient_id` or `local_counter` attributes. that aside, this is some horrific html. i hope this isn't going into production somewhere :\

Comment: I have stepped through using firebug and for some reason they don't come back in the correct order for one of the ordered lists. Maybe I should go by getElementById instead.

@jason, this is not for production. Those are user-defined attributes. How would you recommend fixing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have created a [jsFiddle with working code](http://jsfiddle.net/VQu3S/7/) to solve this problem.  I am including the code here as well just in case jsFiddle goes belly up in the distant future:

```
<ol class="ingredientList">
    <li class="ingredient">Apples</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Carrots</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Clams</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Oysters</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Wheat</li>
</ol>
<ol class="ingredientList">
    <li class="ingredient">Barley</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Eggs</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Millet</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Oranges</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Olives</li>
</ol>​
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(".ingredient").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var added = false;
    var targetList = $(this).parent().siblings(".ingredientList")[0];
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(".ingredient", targetList).each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() > $(element).text()) {
                $(element).insertBefore($(this)).fadeIn("fast");
                added = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(!added) $(element).appendTo($(targetList)).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});​
```

I stripped your HTML down for the sake of brevity, so you will want to modify my code to match yours.  Also, if you are going to use user defined attributes (which are not valid HTML and not officially supported by any browser...though it also won't hurt anything....probably), I recommend prefixing them with "data-" to conform with the [HTML5 Custom Data Attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#custom-data-attribute) specification.  So "ingredient_id" would become "data-ingredient_id".  While this is not yet supported on any current browser as HTML5 has not been finalized, it is safer and more robust than just defining your own attributes.  And once HTML5 is finalized, your attributes will be fully supported.

**Edit** - As John pointed out in the comments, this will not work if you need to support UTF-8 characters.  In this case you need to use [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) (make sure you check that the browser supports it as per the documentation). So that code would look something like this:

```
$(".ingredient").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var added = false;
    var targetList = $(this).parent().siblings(".ingredientList")[0];
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(".ingredient", targetList).each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().localeCompare($(element).text()) > 0) {
                $(element).insertBefore($(this)).fadeIn("fast");
                added = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(!added) $(element).appendTo($(targetList)).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

[Here is an updated Fiddle implementing localeCompare](https://jsfiddle.net/shwbnefe/3/).

Comment: I've tried out your method and it does work when you just use .text(). However, mine also works when you use .text(). Ours both break when I use .attr(). I've stopped using the user-defined attributes and just tried playing around with the `id` attribute and I still get the same strange behavior. A debug tells me that .children() is, in fact, iterating in the correct order. This is so frustrating.

Comment: I do need to sort other ways than alphabetically. I need to also be able to sort by that `local-counter` field in my original HTML.

Comment: I just updated the jsFiddle to order by .attr() and it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/VQu3S/9/

Comment: I think I just figured out what was wrong. Such a n00b mistake too! When comparing the data-local_counter, I did not parseInt(), so it was doing a string compare. Ugh. I think this has fixed it though, and user-defined attributes don't appear to be a problem in Safari or FF on OS X.

Comment: There is problem with your solution if we have UTF-8 character. See http://jsfiddle.net/shwbnefe/

Comment: @John Thanks for pointing that out!  In that case, you need to use the 'localeCompare' function.  I'll update with additional info.

Comment: I like that you put the code in case JSFiddle doesn't exist one day! Never really thought about that, but so many lines of code that were previously linked from stackoverflow would suddenly be gone if it did happen...

Comment: @Hendeca If jsFiddle dissappeared, there would definitely be a great disturbance in the force, as if millions of developers suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.

Comment: This is just one of the very best examples of (good old) js + jquery. Should be used in a textbook or somewhere.

Answer (score -3):

I would get the .text() of each element firs, then put it on an array, sort the array, then move each element where indexes of the SORTED matches the UNSORTED.

and I am too lazy to write the code for that and test it right now :) but just a thought of my way of approaching it.