# Add options to dropdown in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm building a function which will receive an array that contains objects.  I need to populate a list with some values from the objects in the array in alphabetical order.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var options = $("#forms-stage");

var formsTest = [
    {
        name: "Here's a Form",
        category: ["cat1"]
    },
    {
        name: "Sample Form",
        category: ["cat2"]
    },
    {
        name: "zzAnother Form",
        category: ["cat1","cat2"]
    },
];

function allForms(obj) {
    options.empty();
    $.each(obj, function(index, val){

        var add = val.name

        if(options.children().length === 0) {
            options.append("<option>" + val.name + "</option>");
        } else {
            for(i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                if(add > options.children()[i]) {
                    options.append("<option>" + val.name + "</option>");
                }
            }
        }
    })
 };
```

When I use this, I get a list containing "Here's a Form" and then three iterations of "zzAnother Form".  I think the issue is since the loop is iterating through each position, appending options causes problems.

I've looked at other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886739/using-jquery-to-dynamically-insert-into-list-alphabetically) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-insert-alphabetically-list/), but neither of them seem to work with the array of objects situation I have here.

Both those solutions use `$(this)`.  However, simply testing `console.log($(this).name)` leads to three undefined results, and `console.log($(this).name.text())` leads to a "Cannot read property of undefined" error.

Example trying `$(this)` inside the function:

```
 function allForms(obj) {
    options.empty();
    $.each(obj, function(index, val){

        var add = val.name

        console.log($(this).name);
    })
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the `Array` and then append the options using vanilla Javascript `for-loop`

Sort the array just before the `for-loop`

```
obj.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0));
```

```js
var options = $("#forms-stage");

var formsTest = [{
    name: "Here's a Form",
    category: ["cat1"]
  },
  {
    name: "Sample Form",
    category: ["cat2"]
  },
  {
    name: "zzAnother Form",
    category: ["cat1", "cat2"]
  },
];

function allForms(obj) {
  obj.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0));

  options.empty();
  $.each(obj, function(index, val) {
      options.append("<option>" + val.name + "</option>");
  });
};

allForms(formsTest);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="forms-stage"></select>
```

Comment: Wow, I was really over-complicating that.  I even looked at `sort` early on but discarded it.

Comment: @elegant-solutions Great!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the names from the objects in the array with `map`:

```
function allForms(arr) {
  options.empty();
  const names = arr.map(obj => obj.name);
  $.each(names, function(index, val) {
    options.append("<option>" + val + "</option>");
  });
 };
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sbLp2db0/)**